# How to create other threads in main function

Tags: rust, actix-web

I am using the stream function of redis in actix-web 4, I want to create the consumer in the main function, this is my current code

```
[dependencies]
actix-web = "4"
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
redis = { version = "0.21", features = [
  # "cluster",
  "tokio-comp",
  "tokio-native-tls-comp",
] }
```

```rs
#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    utils::init::init_envfile();
    env_logger::init_from_env(env_logger::Env::new());

    let redis_pool = utils::init::init_redis_pool();
    let mysql_pool = utils::init::init_mysql_pool();

    let redist_stream_consumer = web::block(redis_stream_group);

    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .app_data(web::Data::new(redis_pool.clone()))
            .app_data(web::Data::new(mysql_pool.clone()))
       .service(web::scope("/api").configure(controller::api::config))
    })
    .bind(("0.0.0.0", 7777))?
    .run()
    .await?;

    redist_stream_consumer.await.unwrap();
    Ok(())
}

fn redis_stream_group() {
    let client = redis::Client::open("redis://127.0.0.1/").expect("client");
    let mut con = client.get_connection().expect("con");
    let key = "s.order";
    let group_name = "g1";
    let consumer_name = "c1";

    let _: Result<(), _> = con.xgroup_create_mkstream(key, group_name, "$");

    let opts = StreamReadOptions::default()
        .group(group_name, consumer_name)
        .count(1)
        .block(0);

    loop {
        let read_reply: StreamReadReply =
            con.xread_options(&[key], &[">"], &opts).expect("read err");
        for StreamKey { key, ids } in read_reply.keys {
            for StreamId { id, map } in &ids {
                log::info!("id:{} | key:{} | data:{:?}", id, key, map);
            }

            let id_strs: Vec<&String> = ids.iter().map(|StreamId { id, map: _ }| id).collect();
            let _: usize = con.xack(key, group_name, &id_strs).expect("ack err");
        }
    }
}
```

When I use `cargo r`, I can run the program normally and get the sent messages, but when I execute `ctrl+c`, I can't exit the program.

Also I'm not sure if using `web::block` in the `main` function is correct and if there is a better way to run child threads

---

UPDATE: Tried using `tokio::spawn`, seems to work

```rs
#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let redis_pool = utils::init::init_redis_pool();
    let mysql_pool = utils::init::init_mysql_pool();

    for consumer_index in 1..=2 {
        let c_redis_pool = redis_pool.clone();
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            let mut con = c_redis_pool.get().await.unwrap();
            let key = "s.order";
            let group_name = "g1";
            let consumer_name = &format!("c{consumer_index}");
            let _: Result<(), _> = con.xgroup_create_mkstream(key, group_name, "$").await;

            let opts = StreamReadOptions::default()
                .group(group_name, consumer_name)
                .count(1)
                .block(5000);

            loop {
                let read_reply: StreamReadReply = con
                    .xread_options(&[key], &[">"], &opts)
                    .await
                    .expect("err");
                for StreamKey { key, ids } in read_reply.keys {
                    for StreamId { id, map } in &ids {
                        log::info!(
                            "consumer: {} | id:{} | key:{} | data:{:?}",
                            consumer_name,
                            id,
                            key,
                            map
                        );
                    }
                    let id_strs: Vec<&String> =
                        ids.iter().map(|StreamId { id, map: _ }| id).collect();
                    let _: usize = con
                        .xack(key, group_name, &id_strs)
                        .await
                        .expect("ack err");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    let serve = HttpServer::new(move || {
   ...
}
```

Comment: This is a  bit beyond the scope of the question, you will probably get more (and timelier) answers using less code.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the standard library by `use`ing `std::thread` and then creating the thread and whatever you want the other thread to do in a closure

```
fn main() {
    thread::spawn(|| {
        println!("doing things in the thread!");
    });
    println!("doing things outside the thread.... how boring");
}
```

if you want to pass data between them, you can `use std::sync::mpsc` to transfer data between the threads safely and quickly, using `let (item_one,item_two) = mpsc::channel();`, like so

```
fn main() {
   let (sender,receiver) = mpsc::channel();
   thread::spawn(move || {
        let message = String::from("This message is from the thread");
        sender.send(message).unwrap();
   });
   let letter = receiver.recv().unwrap();
```

note that the main thread proceeds as normal until it comes to the `.recv()`, at which it either receives the data from the thread, or waits until the other thread is done.

in your example you could do something like

```
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::thread;
#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    utils::init::init_envfile();
    env_logger::init_from_env(env_logger::Env::new());

    let port = get_env!("ACTIX_PORT", u16);
    log::info!(
        "starting HTTP server at http://{}:{}",
        local_ipaddress::get().unwrap_or("localhost".to_string()),
        port
    );
    let redis_pool = utils::init::init_redis_pool();
    let mysql_pool = utils::init::init_mysql_pool();

    let (consumer_sender,consumer_listener) = mpsc::channel();
    thread::spawn(move || {
        consumer_sender.send(redis_stream_group()).expect("You probably want to handle this case, but I'm too lazy");
    });
    let serve = HttpServer::new(move || {
        let app_state = utils::init::AppState {
            app_name: get_env!("APP_NAME", String),
            pwd_secret: get_env!("PWD_SECRET", String),
            jwt_secret: get_env!("JWT_SECRET", String),
            jwt_exp: get_env!("JWT_EXP", i64),
        };
        App::new()
            .app_data(web::Data::new(awc::Client::default()))
            .app_data(web::Data::new(app_state))
            .app_data(web::Data::new(redis_pool.clone()))
            .app_data(web::Data::new(mysql_pool.clone()))
            .wrap(actix_cors::Cors::default().allowed_origin_fn(|_, _| true))
            .service(web::scope("/chat").configure(controller::chat::config))
            .service(web::scope("/ws").configure(controller::ws::config))
            .service(web::scope("/api").configure(controller::api::config))
    });
    if cfg!(debug_assertions) {
        serve.bind(("0.0.0.0", port))?
    } else {
        let p = format!("/tmp/{}.socket", get_env!("APP_NAME", String));
        let r = serve.bind_uds(&p)?;
        let mut perms = std::fs::metadata(&p)?.permissions();
        perms.set_readonly(false);
        std::fs::set_permissions(&p, perms)?;
        r
    }
    .run()
    .await?;
    let consumer = consumer_listener.recv().unwrap();
    //then put things to do with the consumer here, or not idc
    Ok(())
}

fn redis_stream_group() {
    let client = redis::Client::open("redis://127.0.0.1/").expect("client");
    let mut con = client.get_connection().expect("con");
    let key = "s.order";
    let group_name = "g1";
    let consumer_name = "c1";

    let _: Result<(), _> = con.xgroup_create_mkstream(key, group_name, "$");

    let opts = StreamReadOptions::default()
        .group(group_name, consumer_name)
        .count(1)
        .block(0);

    loop {
        let read_reply: StreamReadReply =
            con.xread_options(&[key], &[">"], &opts).expect("read err");
        for StreamKey { key, ids } in read_reply.keys {
            for StreamId { id, map } in &ids {
                log::info!("id:{} | key:{} | data:{:?}", id, key, map);
            }

            let id_strs: Vec<&String> = ids.iter().map(|StreamId { id, map: _ }| id).collect();
            let _: usize = con.xack(key, group_name, &id_strs).expect("ack err");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it reminded me of the `tokio::spawn` function, I tried it and it worked.